# What does .pluck() method exactly do, in the Reactive extention

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I need to understand what do exactly `pluck()` method do, I found this piece of code as an illustrative example, but when I tried it in angular 4 project, it didn't work as expected:

```
  source: any = Observable.of([
    { value1: 2, value2: 5 },
    { value1: 0, value2: 7},
    { value1: 1, value2: 3 }
  ]).pluck('value1');

  subscribtion = this.source.subscribe(
    function (x) {
    console.log('Next: ' + x);
  },
  function(err) {
    console.log('Error: ' + err);
  },
  function() {
    console.log('Completed');
  });
```

it outputs:

Next: undefined
Completed

Comment: Replace `.of()` by `.from()`. You're creating an observable emitting a single event being an array, instead of emitting the 3 objects in the array.

Comment: That said, the method is documented: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-pluck

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `from`, not `of`?

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet it works for me, and the link was useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
source$ = Rx.Observable.from([   { value1: 2, value2: 5 },   { value1: 0, value2: 7 },   { value1: 1, value2: 3 } ]).pluck("value1");

source$.subscribe(   function(x) {
    console.log("Next: " + x);   },   function(err) {
    console.log("Error: " + err);   },   function() {
    console.log("Completed");   }
```

use from instead of of